# How should carmine's wcar macro be used?

Tags: clojure, redis, carmine

I'm confused by how calls with carmine should be done. I found the `wcar` macro described in [carmine's docs](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/carmine#connections):

```
(defmacro wcar [& body] `(car/with-conn pool spec-server1 ~@body))
```

Do I really have to call `wcar` every time I want to talk to redis in addition to the redis command? Or can I just call it once at the beginning? If so how?

This is what some code with tavisrudd's redis library looked like (from my toy url shortener project's testsuite):

```
(deftest test_shorten_doesnt_exist_create_new_next 
  (redis/with-server test-server
    (redis/set "url_counter" 51)
    (shorten test-url)
    (is (= "1g" (redis/get (str "urls|" test-url))))
    (is (= test-url (redis/get "shorts|1g")))))
```

And now I can only get it working with carmine by writing it like this:

```
(deftest test_shorten_doesnt_exist_create_new_next
  (wcar (car/set "url_counter" 51))
    (shorten test-url)
    (is (= "1g" (wcar (car/get (str "urls|" test-url)))))
    (is (= test-url (wcar (car/get "shorts|1g")))))
```

So what's the right way of using it and what underlying concept am I not getting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dan's explanation is correct.

`Carmine` uses response pipelining by default, whereas `redis-clojure` requires you to ask for pipelining when you want it (using the `pipeline` macro).

The main reason you'd want pipelining is for performance. Redis is so fast that the bottleneck in using it is often the time it takes for the request+response to travel over the network.

[Clojure destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20%28Destructuring%29) provides a convenient way of dealing with the pipelined response, but it does require writing your code differently to `redis-clojure`. The way I'd write your example is something like this (I'm assuming your `shorten` fn has side effects and needs to be called before the `GET`s):

```
(deftest test_shorten_doesnt_exist_create_new_next
  (wcar (car/set "url_counter" 51))
  (shorten test-url)
  (let [[response1 response2] (wcar (car/get (str "urls|" test-url))
                                    (car/get "shorts|1g"))]
    (is (= "1g" response1))
    (is (= test-url response2))))
```

So we're sending the first (`SET`) request to Redis and waiting for the reply (I'm not certain if that's actually necessary here). We then send the next two (`GET`) requests at once, allow Redis to queue the responses, then receive them all back at once as a vector that we'll destructure.

At first this may seem like unnecessary extra effort because it requires you to be explicit about when to receive queued responses, but it brings a lot of benefits including performance, clarity, and [composable commands](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/carmine#commands-are-just-functions).

I'd check out Touchstone on GitHub if you're looking for an example of what I'd consider idiomatic `Carmine` use (just search for the `wcar` calls). (Sorry, SO is preventing me from including another link).

Otherwise just pop me an email (or file a GitHub issue) if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand why this approach is better because it makes it obvious when the connection actually happens.

Answer (score 6):

Don't worry, you're using it the correct way already.

The Redis request functions (such as the get and set that you're using above) are all routed through another function [`send-request!`](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/carmine/blob/66b29f5cd16532cadcab2f38d76d519acd594628/src/taoensso/carmine/protocol.clj#L100) that relies on a dynamically bound `*context*` to provide the connection. Attempting to call any of these Redis commands without that context will fail with a "no context" error. The [`with-conn`](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/carmine/blob/66b29f5cd16532cadcab2f38d76d519acd594628/src/taoensso/carmine.clj#L35) macro (used in `wcar`) sets that context and provides the connection.

The `wcar` macro is then just a thin wrapper around `with-conn` making the assumption that you will be using the same connection details for all Redis requests.

So far this is all very similar to how Tavis Rudd's [redis-clojure](https://github.com/tavisrudd/redis-clojure) works.

So, the question now is why does Carmine need multiple `wcar`'s when Redis-Clojure only required a single `with-server`?

And the answer is, it doesn't. Apart from sometimes, when it does. Carmine's `with-conn` uses Redis's ["Pipelining"](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) to send multiple requests with the same connection and then package the responses together in a vector. The example from the README shows this in action.

```
(wcar (car/ping)
      (car/set "foo" "bar")
      (car/get "foo"))
=> ["PONG" "OK" "bar"]
```

Here you will see that `ping`, `set` and `get` are only concerned with sending the request, leaving the receiving of response up to `wcar`. This precludes asserts (or any result access) from inside of wcar and leads to the separation of requests and multiple `wcar` calls that you have.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to have something like redis-clojure's functionality with carmine? I.e. only say which redis context I want to use once per big block of code? Like in the example with the test case?

Comment: Kind of. But you might not be happy with it. You can put all but the asserts inside a wcar block. The responses from Redis will be returned from wcar in the form of a vector and your asserts will need to act against that. I can't tell from the code what your `shorten` function achieves but you should be ok to run that (as well as any other function) inside the wcar.

Comment: I should add that, even though that is possible, it doesn't mean that I recommend it. I would really suggest keeping the wcar scope as small as it can be.